# Handling Map return type when a method returns null

Tags: java

The method below returns a Map. I am adding a pseudo code skipping how a DAO returns a map of values.

```
public Map<Intger,Integer> getIDsBasingonRanks(){
       Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
       // Dao operation fetcing values from DB;
       if(dao==null){
           //logging some error or info
           return null;// In this cases Null Pointer will be thrown. How to handle it ?
       }
       m.put()// put the values inside the map from DAO
       return m;
}
```

Now I am calling `getIDsBasingonRanks()` from another class which returns Map and get the values from this map

```
Map<Integer,Integer> m2 = getIDsBasingonRanks();
m2.getkey();//Incase the map is null we will have Null Pointer Exception
m2.getValue(); //Incase the map is null we will have Null Pointer Exception
```

I am feeling tricky to handle the return statement from the above method in dao=null condition. How to provide a return to the method when there is null returned to overcome null pointers as we cannot handle them too.

Comment: Check that `m2` isn't `null` before calling any member functions on it (`m2.getKey()` etc). Just like how you checked `dao` wasn't `null` in your `getIDsBasingonRanks` function.

Comment: cool that answered the question. but any other way to give a return for map just like for strings return " ";

Comment: You can use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) if you want a different sort of error detection return.

Comment: Why would you check for dao == null in every fetching method? According to design patterns in java, dao should be instantiated once and hence checked once. You can try and catch NullPointerException as well and handle it in catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to return a null value, you can always return an empty map using Collections class, so your code will become this:

```
public Map<Intger,Integer>getIDsBasingonRanks(){

   Map<Integer,Integer> m =new HashMap<>();
    // Dao operation fetcing values from DB;
        if(dao==null){
            //logging some error or info
        }
        return Collections.emptyMap();// In this case you are returning and empty map which is better
    }

    m.put()// put the values inside the map from DAO
        return m;
```

}

Comment: Better catch NullPointerException and handle the problem with DAO being null rather than pretend everything is fine and have an empty map.

Comment: If i understood, the question was not about what to do with the dao being null, but it about the returned value being null which is not a good practice

Comment: That's why you try and catch it. You don't return null in catch, but do something useful like logging the exception, trying to re-set dao or even returning empty map like you suggested. The point is in try and catch the exception rather than avoid it. Map could be empty not only because dao is null, but fetched result set is empty.

Comment: @Johan: Liked the idea and the answer suits my purpose. All the solutions are great though.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is **Optional**.

```
public Optional<Map<Integer, Integer>> getIDsBasingonRanks() {

    Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
    ... // Dao operation fetcing values from DB;
        if (dao == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

    ... // put the values inside the map from DAO
    return Optional.of(m);
}

getIDsBasingonRanks().ifPresent(m ->
        {
            ... m.get(42) ...
        });

int y = getIDsBasingonRanks().map(m -> m.get(42)).orElse(13);
```

Comment: Upvote for knowing that we have a utility called Optional. I didn't know it. But here it changes the complete signature of the calling method and the already written method.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a `null` value inside your method is something you don't expect? **Throw an exception**. You can create some custom, let's say, `IDNotFoundException`, throw it and catch it. Beware that exceptions are just another resource you can use as a programmer. The only dangerous exceptions are the ones you're not catching

On the other hand, if having a `null` value is something "acceptable" but you want to be careful about that you can just wrap it inside an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your `getIDsBasingonRanks` method is a bit unclear,  it seems like if the read operation somehow fails you will log the error and return `null`.

If that's the case I would use the method with a simple `null`check:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> m2=getIDsBasingonRanks();
if(m2 != null){
    m2.getkey();
    m2.getValue(); 
}
```